# Reverse Terminal Commands - Mac?

Tags: command-line, terminal

I'm using OS X Snow Leopard and typed this cmd into Terminal after reading a blog post that claimed it was a fix for a particular problem I was having, but it has caused other config issues instead. Is there a way to reverse/undo entered commands in Terminal?

This is the code I entered:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 10000
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You have to learn how to delete a rule from the list. You cannot simply "undo" a command. (and this is not a programming related question).

Answer (score 0):

No, it would be quite too complicated for Terminal to know how to undone every possible command... Despite that some commands can't be undone.

In your case, I think it's something like `iptables -t nat -flush` or so. But just read the iptables manpage.